# Can I dynamically build a where clause in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to dynamically build a LINQ query for LINQ to Entities so that I can avoid repeating the same function twice.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
private IUser GetOrUpdateUser(Predicate<IUser> filter, Func<IIdentityProvider, UserRecord> fetch)
{
    var user = (from u in this.adapter.Users
                where filter(u)
                select u).SingleOrDefault();

    if (user == null)
    {
        // User not found.  Add him.
        user = this.adapter.AddUser(fetch(this.idenityProvider));
    }
    else if (user.IsExpired)
    {
        // User found, but expired.  Update him.
        this.adapter.UpdateUser(user, fetch(this.idenityProvider));
    }

    return user;
}

protected IUser GetUserByNetworkId(string username)
{
    return GetOrUpdateUser(
        u => u.NetworkId == username,
        i => i.GetUserByNetworkId(username));
}

protected IUser GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    return GetOrUpdateUser(
        u => u.Email == email,
        i => i.GetUserByEmail(email));
}
```

The `filter` parameter is throwing this exception:

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

I could potentially do this:

```
protected IUser GetUserByNetworkId(string username)
{
    return GetOrUpdateUser(
        from u in this.adapter.Users
        where u.NetworkId == username
        select u,
        i => i.GetUserByNetworkId(username));
}

protected IUser GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    return GetOrUpdateUser(
        from u in this.adapter.Users
        where u.Email == email
        select u,
        i => i.GetUserByEmail(email));
}
```

But, that is not as clean.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two LINQ syntaxes:

```
private IQueryable<IUser> BuildQuery(IQueryable<IUser> users, string userName)
{
    users = users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName);
    return users;
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
var query = from u in this.BuildQuery(this.adapter.Users, userName)
            select u;
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you need to use, e.g., `Expression<Func<...`, not just `Func<...`.

```
Expression<Func<User, Bool>> MakePredicate(int id)
{
    return u => u.Id == id;
}

void DoStuff()
{
    Expression<Func<User, Bool>> pred = MakePredicate(123);
    User u = Context.Users.Where(pred).Single()
}
```

Note that interfaces won't translate to L2E. So you must use `User`, not `IUser` (or the like).

Comment: What syntax would I then use in the `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

There are two notable projects on this.

1. [LINQ Expression Builder](http://expressionbuilder.codeplex.com/), and
2. [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)'s [LinQkit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) which is open source. The PredicateBuilder class demonstrates how to build Linq Query expressions on the Fly.

these references might guide you.

For your immediate use, I suggest Predicatebuilder.